# iptables rule to nat inbound only ports

Tags: iptables, nat

This would be a very long post if I had to explain all the reasons behind this

1. I have to have an application listening on port 8080
2. This application also needs to listen on port 8181 -- but the application doesn't allow a second port.
3. The rules defined have to be automatically rolled out to many different systems all of which have different networking requirements.

So what I have are these rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -i any -j REDIRECT --to-port 8181
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8181
```

This does work. Inbound requests are mapped to from 8181 to 8080 -- however, if this system has to perform a rest call to another system on port 8181 -- it translates the outbound to 8080. Is there a way to specify inbound 8181 without defining the destination IP?  I mean if that's what I have to do I'll write a more complex script to do it, but I was hoping there might be an easier way...

Comment: This question can't be answered without more specifics because how you do it depends on the exact setup as to if its even possible. Are you able to specify a network interface range or type, or control and specify the port the connections are being made from?  Another option might be to set a QOS bit on the systems sending packets and exclude based on that.

Comment: that's the thing. Our systems have some crazy networking. eth0, eth1, eth1:0, eth2, eth3 and then the VIP is on lo:0 and lo:1. Some systems only have eth0, eth1, and the newest they've finally come to their senses and have only one interface, but still use lo:0 for the vip.